# Word for saying negative things in a cheerful manner?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

E.g. Someone says "You smell bad!" but in a cheerful/positive tone, usually for being funny or sarcastic.

The exact words are negative, it's just the body gesture/facial expression/tone being cheerful/positive in a mismatching way.

I'm also looking for a verb form of it, describing the action of expressing the negative meaning with such a manner. E.g. A:"You smell bad!"(in a cheerful manner) B:"Uh, you're ____ it."

Comment: I think "facetious" works well as an adjective and "mask" as a verb.

Comment: If you can’t find a single word for the verb, you could consider “Uh, you’re **sending [me] mixed signals**.”

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps it is [facetious](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/facetious), defined by oed as

> Treating serious issues with deliberately inappropriate humour.

Answer (score 0):

Try [mask](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mask), defined by Merriam Webster under **synonym discussion**

> Suggests some often obvious means of hiding or disguising somethin.

A- you smell bad!

B- uh! You're masking it (with your demeanor)